How to get all PDF files from phone storage in Android above 11 using MediaStoreQuery without taking MANAGE_ALLFILE
    String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"application/pdf"};
    String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_TAKEN, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED}; // Get file paths
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
    Cursor cursor = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL), projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Cursor Lenght : --->  "+cursor.getCount() );
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA));
                String fileDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_TAKEN));
                String fileSize = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE));
                String fileModified = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED));

                Log.e(TAG, "filePath: -----------> " + filePath);
                Log.e(TAG, "fileDate: -----------> " + fileDate);
                Log.e(TAG, "fileSize: -----------> " + fileSize);
                Log.e(TAG, "fileModified: -----------> " + fileModified);

                PC_PDFModel pcPdfModel = new PC_PDFModel();
                File pdfFile = new File(filePath);
                pcPdfModel.setPdfname(filePath);
                pcPdfModel.setPdffile(pdfFile);
                pcPdfModel.setDate(fileDate);
                pcPdfModel.setDatelastmodi(new Date(fileModified));
                pcPdfModel.setSize(fileSize);
                pdfList.add(this.pdfModel);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

here my code but i m trying to fetch .pdf files from storage but get cursor count == 0. how to get all pdf files?
